# CSV to Neo4j-Graph

Tags: r, csv, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to convert database(csv files) to neo4j-graph, but I get an error.
The command is

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/PERC/AppData/Roaming/Neo4j%20Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-37b84fcf-d1b2-4dee-a4ee-5faed9cbaca0/installation-3.3.1/import/customers.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Customer {companyName: row.CompanyName, customerID: row.CustomerID, fax: row.Fax, phone: row.Phone});`
```

The customers.csv file in on import folder of Neo4j Desktop folder. But I get this error:

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/PERC/AppData/Roaming/Neo4j%20Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-37b84fcf-d1b2-4dee-a4ee-5faed9cbaca0/installation-3.3.1/import/Users/PERC/AppData/Roaming/Neo4j%20Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-37b84fcf-d1b2-4dee-a4ee-5faed9cbaca0/installation-3.3.1/import/customers.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your error message, you will see that the actually-used file URL repeats the file path.

As stated in the [dev manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#query-load-csv-introduction):

> File URLs will be resolved relative to the dbms.directories.import
>   directory. For example, a file URL will typically look like `file:///myfile.csv` or `file:///myproject/myfile.csv`.

Since your CSV file is directly in your import directory, try this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///customers.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Customer {companyName: row.CompanyName, customerID: row.CustomerID, fax: row.Fax, phone: row.Phone});
```